# Can't manage use the function : predict() in tensorflow(keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

[This is a continuation to my lsat question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543640/cant-manage-to-use-the-model-predict-in-kerastensorflow/60543947?noredirect=1#comment107155611_60543947)

I'm getting errors saying that something went wrong with the predict function, I tried reading about those errors and I don't understand what they mean.

I have a 1 dimensional array(vector) that I try to predict with if a file is a virus or not.

this is my now improved code(thank you [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx))

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tensorflow import keras
import vector_build

model = keras.models.load_model("anti_virus_model.h5")


def predict_file(fname):
    print(fname)  # Debugging
    pe = vector_build.encode_pe(fname)
    print(pe)  # Debugging
    result = model.predict(pe)
    print(result)  # Debugging
    return result


def browse_file():
    fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("exe files", "*.exe"),))
    result = predict_file(fname)
    # TODO: Do something with `result`


def ui_main():
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("Browser")
    broButton = Tk.Button(master=root, text="Browse", width=80, height=25, command=browse_file)
    broButton.pack(side=Tk.LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

    Tk.mainloop()


if True:  # First make this branch work correctly,
    predict_file("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")
else:  # ... then switch to this.
    ui_main()
```

**the problem:**
I get this error and don't understand what should I do to solve it:
**(the actual vector is much bigger, I shortened it)**

```
2020-03-07 15:26:58.306607: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-03-07 15:26:58.306740: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-03-07 15:27:01.172350: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-03-07 15:27:01.172465: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-03-07 15:27:01.176427: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-GT2BTVK
2020-03-07 15:27:01.176585: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-GT2BTVK
2020-03-07 15:27:01.176923: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:Sequential models without an `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer state. As a result, your model isstarting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

[1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.33333333e-01] 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/0123m/PycharmProjects/anti_virus_project/predictorUI.py", line 34, in <module>
    predict_file("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")
  File "C:/Users/0123m/PycharmProjects/anti_virus_project/predictorUI.py", line 13, in predict_file
    result = model.predict(pe)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1013, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 498, in predict
    workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 426, in _model_iteration
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 646, in _process_inputs
    x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2346, in _standardize_user_data
    all_inputs, y_input, dict_inputs = self._build_model_with_inputs(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2572, in _build_model_with_inputs
    self._set_inputs(cast_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2659, in _set_inputs
    outputs = self(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 737, in __call__
    self.name)
  File "C:\Users\0123m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 213, in assert_input_compatibility
    ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 486 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

do I need to change the format of the vector? or what should I do to fix this error.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

When I extracted data from my data base it was actually a 2d array, and when I built a vector it was 1d so the model didn't recognize the shape of it.

changing predict(pe) to predict(pe[None]) did the job!

credit to: [xdurch0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393102/xdurch0)